# "this" vs. $scope in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I know similar questions have been asked, and I have read the answers, but I still don't get this, so any help will be appreciated.

The code below works. However, if I use `$scope` instead of `this` before the `bindTest` and `clickTest` functions (lines 3 and 6), it does not work. Can anyone tell me why? From what I've read, I would have expected `$scope` to work here.

On the other hand, if I use `this` instead of `$scope` before `offOrOn` (line 8), that does **not** work.

```js
angular.module('myTestApp', [])
        .controller('MyTestController', function($scope) {
          this.bindTest = function() {
            console.log("bindTest");
          }; 
          this.clickTest = function() {
            console.log("clickTest");
            $scope.offOrOn = 'on';
          };       
        });
```

```css
button {
 height:25px;
 width:25px; 
}
.on {
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myTestApp" ng-controller="MyTestController as tester">
 <p ng-bind="tester.bindTest()"></p>
 <button ng-class="offOrOn" ng-click="tester.clickTest()"></button>
</div>
</body>
```

Also, as an aside, I tried to create [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhurwicz/8x15272c/4/), but it doesn't work, and the Chrome dev console tells me it won't load the module.  I'm curious what's wrong there.  But it's great that stackoverflow now provides an identical function that does work!

Comment: Since `$scope` is not the same as `this` I wonder where you get the idea from that exchanging those should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `controller as` syntax. That means that everything added to `this` is accessible using `tester.` and everything added to `$scope` can be used (only) **without** `test.`.

Now it should be clear why `this.offOrOn` doesn't work: In your HTML you don't use `tester.offOrOn`.